# populate all div ids in a page with javascript

Tags: html, populate

I am tryin to populate a list of all Div ids on a page with javascript. The below code gives me a count of all divs but not a list of div ids which i am looking for, Please help

```
 var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
 for(var i=0, len=divs.length; i < len; i++){
 document.write(divs[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 document.write(divs[i].id);
```

Comment: want to do it with javascript

Comment: Try: document.write(divs[i].id);